# How to analyze the force on the ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Imagine a disk spinning at the angular velocity $\omega$. There is a small ball on it. Friction is negligible, so the ball is at rest. Now we take the disk as the reference system. The small ball moves around the disk with an angular velocity of $\omega$, and it is subject to inertial centrifugal force. So why can it maintain circular motion and where does its centripetal force come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the rotating frame, there are two forces acting on the ball:  an outward centrifugal force of magnitude $m r \omega^2$ and an inward [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) of magnitude $2m \omega v = 2 m r \omega^2$.  These two forces combine to yield a net inward force of $m r \omega ^2$, which is sufficient to keep the ball moving in a circle of radius $r$ in the rotating frame.